# Is it possible to interecept a print call in chrome and dump it as html, using extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printing

I have found a demonstration for how to call arbitrary functions using the [`window.matchMedia`](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) API. But I can't tell if it's possible to actually a write an extention that will intercept the print call and dump something other than postscript.

My motivation is to intercept a print call from an extension called "printfriedly & pdf" and save its output as .doc or .html. The extension is useful for cleaning up pages before printing, but it doesn't allow you to save it's output as html or doc. The printfiendly extension brings up an iframe with the cleaned up document, but when I click on "inspect frame" (in the hopes of getting the html that way), I just get an empty tab.

Comment: I guess you can add a button that invokes [chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture).

Comment: would that capure the stuff getting sent to the printer, or just the page? The problem is that the printfriendly's iframe is not actually part of the page. i took a look at printfriendly's code and all it does is make add a lister, with everything else being done by the server.

Comment: Hmm, to intercept printing you'll have to use [chrome.printerProvider API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider) and use a converter from PDF to another format or write your own, I'm afraid.